# can I get header parameters from passport-auth-token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

```
passport.use('authtoken', new LocalTokenStrategy(
    function(token, done) {
        console.log(token)
        return done(null, "success")
    }
));



router.post('/protect',
    passport.authenticate(
        'authtoken', {
            session: false,
            optional: false
        }
    ),
    (req, res) => {
        res.send("token")
    }
);
```

can I get header parameters inside `passport.use` here I use `passport-auth-token` strategy. I want to get the token from the header parameter of the  HTTP request.

Comment: check [this example](https://medium.com/hyphe/token-based-authentication-in-node-6e8731bfd7f2).

Comment: the problem was resolved by using _passport-http-header-strategy_ instead of _passport-auth-token_